# Misunderstanding with viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Can I do different activity in instantiateItem() ?
please check my screenshot link..

In this screen shot,red TextView is wrote in instantiateItem()....When drag the screen,it follow...

So,I want to insert different layout and activity instead of this TextView..Can I code these in instantiateItem() ?

> http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=zlagwn&s=5#.UqbeWye_80k

This is MyPageAdapter.java

```
public class MyPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Context ctx;

public MyPageAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        LayoutInflater vi=(LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v=vi.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
    Button btnRefresh=(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnRefreshGold);
    btnRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // my operation
        }
    });

    ((ViewPager)container).addView(v,0);
    return v;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return (view == object);
}
```

this is main.xml

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TabWidget>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Tab1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnRefreshGold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/btnRefresh" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/myListView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand

Comment: I'm just insert different activity,layout in instatiateItem()..Can I do?

Comment: You can't insert another 'activity' into a viewpager (although you can start another from it). A viewpager is a ViewGroup subclass. You can add view objects such as Buttons, TextViews, even Layouts to a ViewPager but not an entire activity.

Comment: In my screenshot,I'm dragging the screen,so you can see half of Red TextView..I want different activities instead of this TextView...Please see screenshot, button is not move(button is in the R.layout.main.xml)..

Comment: Do you know what you want in each position?

Comment: please..what do you mean sir?

Comment: Ok lets say you have 3 tabs as you have in your image - what you want is the text in tab one should be different from the text in tab two and also different from the one in tab 3 right?

Comment: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=30iw85v&s=5#.UqbwBSe_80k  this is original(no screen dragging)    http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2j1rlfd&s=5#.UqbxxCe_80k   this is screen dragging and button clicked..Output is ListView

Comment: I want button and listview sliding like a Red TextView..Now,in my screenshot,they are dead..

Comment: So the buttons are not working?

Comment: when button is clicked,the result is listview..now I'm edited my post with main.xml..please check it.. I want buttons and ListView together sliding...but it isn't work..

Comment: You haven't instantiated your Button in instantiateItem(). you need to do that first

Comment: How is that? please write some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my answer..fix at instantiateItem()

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

```
    LayoutInflater vi=(LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
v=vi.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
Button btnRefresh=(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnRefreshGold);
btnRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // my operation
    }
});

((ViewPager)container).addView(v,0);
return v;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `instantiateItem()` :

```
   Button button = (Button) container.findViewById(R.id.btnRefreshGold);
   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

   @override
   public void onClick(View v){
        //do what you want your button to do when clicked here
  });
```

You can go follow [this link](https://github.com/ivywireline/FreePirateApp/tree/01ffc3da861c37558a8c68132a1e52763b24c906/FreePirateApp) to see a sample of what your viewpager should look like.

Comment: sir, github.com/ivywireline/FreePirateApp/tree/… I can't test this..please check this screenshot tinypic.com/view.php?pic=3462jd4&s=5 I can click only instructions and share buttons..but there is nothing to learn with viewpager..When I click medium button, it stopped unfortunately..anyway,thank for help :) but I can't still solve my problem..

Comment: it's not convenient with your code sir..It's unfortunately stopped.. Button button = (Button) container.findViewById(R.id.btnRefreshGold);  this line can't insert..I edit like this...http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=o7w18h&s=5#.Uqf8Mie_80k                               Button button=new Button(ctx);
  button.setText("btnRefreshGold");
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   public void onClick(View v) {
       ConnectToServer cNTS = new ConnectToServer(ctx,myListView, newsList);
    cNTS.execute(urlGoldAddress);
   }
  });
  container.addView(button);
  return button;

Comment: I think I can nearly solve my error..I edited the post..please check my edited code..

Comment: yes,it works..see my screenshot... http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=73cxn8&s=5#.Uqgwvye_80k  I used same layout(.xml) so left Refresh button is static..right button can slide when dragging the screen

Comment: sorry for late reply..I re-combine my code..Now, I finally got the 100% result that I want..thanks for helping me :)  I want you to give reputation but I need some reputation..Anyway,thank you very much..

Comment: I answer my own question :D